# Is there any need to create my own buffer for file I/O operations in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, file, io, buffer

Is there any need to use a custom buffer to either read or write files in C or C++ to reduce file I/O?

For example, if you need to read a file entry by entry (one char at a time, or one struct at a time), is it recommended to reduce the number of calls to fread() using a buffer? Does it make any difference in I/O (for read and write)?
Does the answer depend on the Operational System or anything else not in the code?

I've learned that this was recommended, but today someone told me about `setvbuf()` on `stdio.h`, and it seems that everything is already there and you don't need to add this complexity to your program.

Looking at stackoverflow, I've found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4413718/291609) with no votes claiming that there is no significant difference between using `fgetc`/`setvbuf()` vs. `fgets`. Is that really true?

Comment: You should probably benchmark this yourself, as it might differ a lot between use-cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions in `<stdio.h>` all do their own buffering.  There are
exceptions, but generally, I would expect them to be optimized for the
system they're running on, with regards to e.g. buffer size.  In which
case, I would expect using `setvbuf()` to be a pessimisation in all but
a few very special cases.

Answer (score 3):

The `fread()` function already implements buffering to avoid calling the lower-level `read()` too often.  You shouldn't worry about it unless you do some benchmarks and find out that file I/O is taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::istream` object requres a `std::streambuf` object associated with it to actually perform read operations.

The implementation for file of istream (`ifstream`) internally has a `fstreambuf` that does just that.